# Reading books information from txt file in C++?

Tags: c++, file, structure, getline, display

I want to read books - their title, author and price from a txt file. `The 3 properties of the book are separated by '|' - Title|Author|Book.` However, I do not know exactly how to do this. I have the structure Book, with 3 elements. I want, for each line to read the book title, author and price, save them to the 3 variables of the structure respectively and print them on the console. I have tried to do this with the title only, but it print the whole line. I would like to ask how can I print for each books separately its author title and price?

Comment: getline will read the entire line.  After that, you need to parse it dependent on the format of your lines.

Comment: `while(!p.eof()){` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Comment: What is the benefit of using `ptstr`? Why not simply use `a.title`?

Comment: ***However, I do not know exactly how to do this.*** It depends on how the file is written. How do you separate the 3 different items on a line?

Comment: There are quite a few tutorials online, and of course you should get [a good beginners book or two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/440558) to read.

Comment: `getline` has two main uses: `getline(stream, line)` to get a line and `getline(stream, token, delimiter)` to get a token. Put a `std::stringstream` into the mix to allow you to parse the line as a stream and you're pretty much done.

Comment: Please do not rush into accepting an answer. The one posted below, that you have already accepted, is wrong.

Comment: This issue is similar to reading CSV (Comma Separated Values) format, except you are using '|' instead of ','.  Please search the internet for "c++ read file CSV" for examples.

Comment: Do you mean `Title|Author|Price`? Can you post a sample of the input file format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The include libraries you will need, and your `Book` structure definition. Once you get to study slightly more advanced C++ topics you could learn how to overload friend functions for input and output streams to make your I/O operations self-contained for a `Book` object.

```
#include <iostream> ///< std::cout
#include <fstream>  ///< std::ifstream
#include <sstream>  ///< std::istringstream, std::string
#include <vector>   ///< std::vector

struct Book
{
    std::string title;  ///< title of the book
    std::string author; ///< author of the book
    std::string price;  ///< price of the book (TODO use float instead?)
    // TODO consider friend std::istream& operator>> for parsing input data
    // TODO consider friend std::ostream & operator<< for printing object
};
```

If you have a handle to your input file you could parse it like this. Read each line at a time. [Do not read until input.eof()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong) because it's wrong! Store each line into a temporary `std::istringstream` object for further parsing. Use the overloaded `std::getline(stream, token, delimiter)` with `|` to parse the data in the line, and save them directly into your temporary `Book` object. Finally, store the object into your vector if you want to be able to process them later, and optionally print them to the console.

```
void readBooks(std::ifstream& input, std::vector<Book>& books)
{
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(input, line)) ///< while we have a line to parse
    {
        std::istringstream iss(line); ///< line to parse as sstream
        Book book; ///< temporary book object
        std::getline(iss, book.title, '|');
        std::getline(iss, book.author, '|');
        std::getline(iss, book.price, '|');
        books.push_back(book); ///< add book object into vector
        std::cout << "Title:  " << book.title << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Author: " << book.author << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Price:  " << book.price << std::endl << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<Book> books;  ///< store each Book object
    std::ifstream input("books.txt");
    if (input.is_open())
    {
        readBooks(input, books); ///< read your books
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Tested with the following input file contents

> ```
> Tales from Shakespeare (1807)|Shakespeare|6.74
> The Jungle Book (1894)|Rudyard Kipling|9.99
> Through the Looking-Glass (1871)|Lewis Carroll|12.97
> ```

Yielded the following results

> ```
> Title:  Tales from Shakespeare (1807)
> Author: Shakespeare
> Price:  6.74
>
> Title:  The Jungle Book (1894)
> Author: Rudyard Kipling
> Price:  9.99
>
> Title:  Through the Looking-Glass (1871)
> Author: Lewis Carroll
> Price:  12.97
> ```

Answer (score -3):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

struct Book {
    string title;
    string author;
    string price;
};
void read_Books(std::ifstream&, Book&);

int main()
{
    ifstream p("books.txt", ios::in);
    Book a;
    read_Books(p, a);
    return 0;
}
void read_Books(std::ifstream& p, Book& ptstr) {
    while(p.is_open() && !p.eof()){
        getline(p, ptstr.title, '|');
        getline(p, ptstr.author, '|');
        getline(p, ptstr.price, '|');
        cout<<ptstr.title << ptstr.author << ptstr.price << std::endl;
        //The whole line is printed, it ought to be the title only
    }
}
```

Comment: No. That is not how to read from a stream in a loop. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong, several times.

Comment: And what exactly is the point of passing in a reference to a `Book` object if you're just going to be overwriting it again and again? Maybe a reference to a `std::vector<Book>` would make more sense here?